# Prevent cursor from moving outside of GLFW window bounds?

Tags: c, linux, glfw

I'm using OpenGL and C, with GLFW for the window. I've enabled

```c
glfwSetInputMode(window.self, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

but the cursor is not locked, and moves outside of the window, constricting 360 degrees+ camera movement. Here is my camera code for handling mouse input for reference:

```c
void cameraMouseCallback(double xposIn, double yposIn) {
    float xpos = xposIn;
    float ypos = yposIn;

    /*printf("%f %f\n", window.width/2 - xpos, window.width/2 - ypos);
    glfwSetCursorPos(window.self, window.width/2, window.height/2);*/

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // Reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top
    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    xoffset *= camera.sensitivity;
    yoffset *= camera.sensitivity;

    yaw += xoffset;
    pitch += yoffset;

    // Make sure that when pitch is out of bounds, screen doesn't get flipped
    if (pitch > 89.0f)
        pitch = 89.0f;
    if (pitch < -89.0f)
        pitch = -89.0f;

    vec3 front;
    front[0] = cos(glm_rad(yaw)) * cos(glm_rad(pitch));
    front[1] = sin(glm_rad(pitch));
    front[2] = sin(glm_rad(yaw)) * cos(glm_rad(pitch));

    glm_vec3_normalize(front);

    glm_vec3_copy(front, cameraFront);
}
```

I tried using `glfwSetCursorPos(window.self, window.width/2, window.height/2);` to lock the cursor to the center of the screen, and using the center position subtracted by the mouse position to get the delta, then incrementing that. However, this also doesn't work. What can I do to fix this, so that the mouse doesn't move off the window, and also allows for free camera/mouse movement?

Comment: I'm using a linux based system, and I'd like to implement this functionality through GLFW, not through some other third-party implementation.

Comment: Which windowing system?  X11?  Wayland?  Framebuffer?

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this functionality just through GLFW? Won't using a specific windowing system limit the functionality to only some systems?